# Как сделать зеркала директорий через htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Приветствую всех.
Никак не могу сделать зеркала директорий, ну что бы, к примеру site.com/en/ site.com/ru/ и site.com/de/ вели на site.com. Редиректа быть не должно, просто url'ы должны считаться зеркалами. Но количество таких директорий должно быть ограничено, вроде (ru | en | de) и должны работать GET запросы, как site.com/en/?get=get так и site.com/?get=get
Записи типа

```
Alias / /ru/
```

вызывают только ошибку 500

Answer (score 1):

Это в htaccess

```
RewriteEngine    on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/favicon.ico

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

А дальше прописать уже в отдельном файлике.

Comment: Гениально, но эта мысль мне в голову пришла до написания вопроса, потому собственно я и написал теги Apache и htaccess. Что именно писать я не знаю)

Comment: спасибо, но как сделать ограниченное количество зеркальных директорий? (ru | en| de) куда?